When do algebraic elements form a subalgebra?
If $R$ is a commutative ring and $A$ is a commutative $R$-algebra, we say that an element $x\in A$ is algebraic over $R$ if $x$ is a root of a nonzero polynomial $f \in R[X]$, or equivalently, if the "evaluation at $x$" $R$-algebra homomorphism $R[X]\to A$ is not injective. If we require $f$ to be monic, we get instead the notion of integral elements, and it is well-known that the elements of $A$ that are integral over $R$ form an $R$-subalgebra. It is therefore natural to ask whether the algebraic elements also form a subalgebra.
If $R$ is a field, then algebraic elements coincide with integral elements and therefore form a subalgebra; if $R$ is only an integral domain, we may argue as follows: it suffices to show that for any two algebraic elements $x,y\in A$, the subalgebra $S$ generated by $x$ and $y$ consists solely of algebraic elements, i.e. there is no injective $R$-algebra homomorphism from $R[X]$ to $S$. Consider $K=\text{Frac}(A)$ and the $K$-algebra $K\otimes_R S$ generated by $1\otimes x$ and $1\otimes y$, which are still algebraic because $R\to K$ is injective. Any injective $R[X]\to S$ would induce injective $K[X]\to K\otimes_R S$ due to flatness of $K/R$, which is impossible by the field case.
We may consider a simplified version of this, namely whether an algebra generated by a single algebraic element $x$ consists solely of algebraic elements. For this simplified question, the argument above allows us to reduce to local rings $R$: if $x$ is a root of a nonzero polynomial in $R[X]$, the polynomial remains nonzero in $R_{\mathfrak{m}}[X]$ for some maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}\subset R$. (But given two elements and two nonzero polynomials they are roots of, there may not exist a single $\mathfrak{m}$ such that both polynomials remain nonzero in $R_{\mathfrak{m}}[X]$.)
There are in fact ways to produce polynomials having $x+y$, $xy$ and $f(x)$ (for $f\in R[X]$) as roots via resultants, given polynomials having $x$ and $y$ as roots, but the problem is that we may get the zero polynomial. For example, zero is what we get if we try to produce a polynomial having $1+X+X^2\in \mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}[X]/\langle2X^3\rangle$ as a root by computing $\text{res}_X(2X^3,Z-(1+X+X^2))$. However, the following Singular code nonetheless shows that $1+X+X^2$ is a root of $2(X^3+X^2+X+1)$:
ring r=(integer, 4), (x), lp;
map f=r,1+x+x2;
ideal i=2x3;
preimage(r,f,i);

and I've been unable to find a counterexample after experimentations along this line.
I'm therefore asking: for which classes of commutative rings $R$ do we have
(1) every element in an $R$-algebra generated by an algebraic element is algebraic;
(2) algebraic elements form a subalgebra;
(3) idempotency of "algebraic closure" / transitivity of algebraicity: if $x \in A$ is a root of a nonzero polynomial in $A[X]$ with $R$-algebraic coefficients, then $x$ is itself algebraic.
YCor gave a counterexample for (2) (and therefore (3)) in the comments, and darij grinberg pointed out that this question contains a counterexample to (1).

Write $A=k[u,y]/(y^2-y)$, $R=k[y]/(y^2-y)$. Then $uy$ and $u(1-y)$ are "algebraic" over $R$, but not their sum $u$. Indeed, $P(uy)=Q(u(1-y))=0$, where $P(X)=(1-y)X$ and $Q(X)=yX$.

@YCor Thank you! I adjusted the question accordingly.

In Ycor's example, $u(1-y) \in A$ is algebraic over $R[uy]$ (and in fact over $R$), but $u \in A = R[uy][u(1-y)] = R[u]$ is not.  So (1) can fail, too.  Probably you want at least o assume that the leading coefficient of the polynomial is a nonzerodivisor in your definition of algebraic.

For general $R$ and $A$, if $u,v\in A$ satisfy $f(u)=0=g(v)$ for $f,g\in R[X]$ with leading coefficients $a,b$, respectively, then $au$ and $bv$ are integral over $R$. Hence so are $ab(u+v)$ and $abuv$. So $u+v$ and $uv$ are algebraic over $R$, unless of course $ab=0$ ...

It appears that $x\in A$ is not necessarily algebraic if $rx$ is integral for some $0\ne r \in R$. We'd get $(rx)^n+c_1(rx)^{n-1}+\dots+c_{n-1}(rx)+c_n=0$ but it may happen that $r^n, c_1 r^{n-1}, \dots, c_{n-1}r, c_n$ are all zero. But this argument does give a simpler proof for the integral domain case; thanks!

If you assume that $r$ is nonzero and not nilpotent, then $x \in A$ is algebraic if $rx$ is integral.  On the other hand, if $r$ is nonzero and nilpotent, them $rx$ is integral for all $x \in A$, but you would not expect all $x \in A$ to be algebraic.  Can your definition of algebraic be altered somehow to put further restrictions on the leading coefficient (e.g., at the very least, not idempotent)?

For question 1, the answer is not all commutative rings. See https://mathoverflow.net/questions/132174/are-roots-of-transcendental-elements-transcendental .

Partial answer: for the case of reduced $R$, one has (2) $\Leftrightarrow$ $R$ is a domain.
For, let $R$ be any ring, reduced or not, containing non-zero elements $a,b$ such that $aR$ $\cap$ $bR=0$. (E.g.: $R$ is a reduced ring but not a domain; then if $ab=0$ and $x\in aR\cap bR$, say $x$ $=$ $au$ $=$ $bv$, one has $x^2$ $=$ $abuv$ $=0$; hence $x=0$; thus indeed $aR$ $\cap$ $bR=0$.) We produce an $R$-algebra $A$ for which (2) fails.
Take $A=R[X,Y]/(aX,bY)$. Then $\overline{X},\overline{Y}\in A$ are algebraic over $R$, but $z$ $:=$ $\overline{X}$ $+$ $\overline{Y}$ is not. For suppose $H(z)$ $=$ $0$ in $A$, for some $H$ $=$ $\sum_{\,0\le i\le n}c_iZ^i$ $\in R[Z]$. Then $\sum_{\,0\le i\le n}c_i(X+Y)^i$ $=$ $aXF$ $+$$ bYG$ in $B$ $:=$$R[X,Y]$, for suitable $F,G$ $\in$ $B$. Clearly, $c_0$ $=$ $0$. And for $i$ $>$ $0$, the coefficient of $X^i$ on the left-hand side is $c_i$, while on the right it is $a$ times the coefficient in $F$ of the monomial $X^{i-1}$. So $c_i$ $\in$ $aR$. Likewise, comparing coefficients for $Y^i$ on both sides, $c_i$ $\in$ $bR$. Since $aR$ $\cap$ $bR=0$, we obtain $c_i$ $=$ $0$, and therefore $H$ $=$ $0$. Thus (2) does not hold for $R$. (Indeed, the algebraic elements do not even form an additive subgroup of $A$.)
Added 2024/12/03:
On the positive side, (2) is true for every finite local principal ideal ring $(R,\mathfrak{m})$, such as $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. One has $\mathfrak{m}$ $=$ $\pi R$, with $\pi^n$ $=$ $0$ for some $n$, minimal. And every nonzero element of $R$ is of the form $\varepsilon\pi^i$ with $\varepsilon$ a unit and $0$ $\le$ $i$ $<$ $n$. Let $A$ be a $R$-algebra. Then $\pi^m$ $=$ $0$ in $A$, for a minimal $m$ $\le$ $n$. If $m$ $<$ $n$, all elements of $A$ are algebraic over $R$: they are zeros of $\pi^mZ$ $\in$ $R[Z]-\{0\}$. So assume $m$ $=$ $n$, and let $x,y$ $\in$ $A$ be algebraic over $R$. Say $\sum_{0\le i\le t}$ $c_ix^i$ $=$ $0$ in $A$, with the $c_i$ $\in$ $R$ not all zero. Put $\lambda$ $:=$ $\pi^{n-1}$. There exists a unique $0$ $\le$ $j$ $<$ $n$ such that, for all $0$ $\le$ $i$ $\le$ $t$, $d_i:$ $=$ $\pi^jc_i$ is either zero or an associate of $\lambda$ in $R$, and not every $d_i$ vanishes. Then $\sum_{0\le i\le s}$ $d_ix^i$ $=$ $0$ for some $s$ $\le$ $t$ with $d_s$ $\ne$ $0$. As $\lambda$ $\ne$ $0$ in $A$, necessarily $s$ $>$ $0$. So $\lambda x^s$ $\in$ $\sum_{0\le i<s}$ $\lambda Rx^i$. It follows that, for every $k$ $>$ $s$, $\lambda x^k$ is also in this $R$-submodule of $A$. Hence $\lambda R[x]$ $=$ $\sum_{0\le i<s}$ $\lambda Rx^i$. In the same vein, $\lambda R[y]$ $=$ $\sum_{0\le j<t}$ $\lambda Ry^j$ for some $0$ $<$ $t$ $\in$ $\mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $\lambda R[x,y]$ $=$ $\sum_{0\le i<s,\,0\le j<t}$ $\lambda Rx^iy^j$. But this is a finite set. Since it contains $\lambda(x+y)^k$ for every $k$ $>$ $0$, we must have $\lambda(x+y)^{k_1}$ $=$ $\lambda(x+y)^{k_2}$ for certain positive integers $k_1$ $>$ $k_2$, so that $x+y$ is a zero of $\lambda Z^{k_1}$ $-$ $\lambda Z^{k_2}$ $\in$ $R[Z]$. Similarly, $xy$ is a zero of a nontrivial polynomial of the same type.

What do you think happens if you change the definition of algebraic so that the polynomial at which it vanishes is a nonzerodivisor in the polynomial ring (or, equivalently, so that its content is a nonzerodivisor in the ring)?  Maybe then the algebraic elements form a subalgebra?

$f\in R[X]$ is a zerodivisor iff $rf=0$ for some $0\ne r\in R$ (Atiyah & MacDonald, Ch. 1, ex. 2.iii). In $R=\mathbb{Z}[a,b,c,d]/(a^2,ac,c^2,ad+bc)$ one has $\mathrm{ann}(b)$ $=$ $\mathrm{ann}(d)$ $=$ $0$, so $f$ $=$ $aX+b$ and $g$ $=$ $cX+d$ are regular in $R[X]$. The resultant giving a polynomial that kills the sum of a zero of $f$ and one of $g$ is $\mathrm{res}_X(f(X),g(Y-X))$ $=$ $acY+ad+bc$, which is zero. So in $A$ $=$ $R[X,Y]/(f(X),g(Y))$, $X$ and $Y$ are algebraic (in your sense) but their sum is not, I think. (Of course, $bc$ $=$ $0$ in $A$, so $R\to A$ is not an injection here.)

Sorry, this example is no good. Since $bd=0$ in $A$, every element of $A$ is algebraic over $R$ in your sense, as it is a zero of $bdZ$, a nonzerodivisor in $R[Z]$. (Note that $bd$ $=$ $(-aX)(-cY)$ $=$ $acXY$ $=$ $0$ in $A$.)
